# Mathematical and Coding logic to be used for reaching a target number from 0

Tags: algorithm, logic, mathematical-optimization

So here's what I am stuck with:

**Problem:**
Find the minimum number of steps required to reach a target number `x` from 0 (zero), using only two operations: +1 *(add 1 to the number)* or *2 *(multiply 2 with the number)*.

**Here's what I thought/found out:**

> **Method 1:** Suppose the number is 29, start by adding 1 to 0
>   (current_ans: 1), then keep multiplying 2 to the current_ans till we
>   reach the closest value to 29, in this case it becomes 16 (operations:
>   +1 *2 *2 *2 *2). Then keep adding 1 to get the required number (`operations: +1 *2 *2 *2 *2 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1`).
>   But, this method does not give an efficient solution as the total
>   number of steps are 18, whereas it can be done in 8 steps using the
>   2nd method (mentioned below).

Here's the code snippet to do the same:

```
int count = 0, current_ans = 0, old_value, x = 29; //x is the number to reach
while(current_ans != x)
{
    old_value = current_ans;
    if(current_ans == 0)
    {
        current_ans++;
        count++;
    }
    if(current_ans < x)
    {
        current_ans *= 2;
        count++;
        continue;
    }
    if(current_ans > x)
    {
        current_ans = old_value;
        count += x - current_ans;
        current_ans = x;
    }
}
```

> **Method 2:** Let us take same number 29 and convert it to **binary**, which
>   is 11101. So starting from 0, we take the first step as +1
>   (current_ans: 1). Next, we multiply by 2 and convert it to binary
>   (current_ans: 10). Similarly, other operations include +1
>   (current_ans: 1) *2 (current_ans: 10) +1 (current_ans: 11) *2
>   (current_ans: 110) +1 (current_ans: 111) *2 (current_ans: 1110) *2
>   (current_ans: 11100) +1 (current_ans: 11101) and we get the required
>   answer in 8 steps, which is the right answer.

Here's the code snippet to do the same:

```
int count = 0, current_ans = 0, old_value, x = 29; //x is the number to reach
while(current_ans != x)
{
    old_value = current_ans;
    if(current_ans == 0)
    {
        current_ans++;
        count++;
    }
    if(current_ans < x) //I am not really sure of this condition
    {
        current_ans = current_ans << 1;
        count++;
        continue;
    }
}
```

So, I don't know how to convert my logic to a working code in **C/C++/Java/Python**. If anyone has a better solution or a code snippet towards solving the same would be really helpful. I checked out other related questions too, but they didn't really help me with my query. For Method 2, I know I can use left shift operation, but how exactly do I use it if there's no other better solution?

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:** Added the code snippets :)

Comment: show us your effort, dont just ask us to solve your homework

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts

Comment: I am just asking for a logic that would work 100% of the times. And the methods that are mentioned are actually the work that you are talking about. And please read the entire query/question, I have worked/thought of those 2 methods to solve it. My problem is that I am unable to convert it to the working code.

Comment: You *say* that you have thought of 2 methods to solve it but you have not *shown* that to us. Please show code attempts or narrow your question. Also, what do you mean by "I know I can use left shift operation, but how exactly do I use it if there's no other better solution"? That is not clear. Finally, I can think of several approaches to solving this problem in Python. What kind of approach do you want--a low-level approach usable in any language, or a quick, high-level approach that is pythonic?

Comment: to implement your second attempt you can notice that each "0" bit in the target value corresponds to a single operation (an *2); and each "1" bit in the target value corresponds to two operations (an *2 followed by a +1). However, the first *2 is not necessary (as it has no effect since we start from 0) -- thus the total number of operations will be 2 * [number of bits with value 1] + [number of bits with value 0] - 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to work backwards. Start from the number you need:

1. Subtract 1 if the number is odd.
2. Divide by 2 if the number if even.
3. Stop when you get to zero.

For example, for 29, you get 28, 14, 7, 6, 3, 2, 1, 0.

---

C code, intentionally undocumented:

```
int main() {
    int steps = 0;
    int x = 29;
    for (; x; x = x % 2 ? x - 1 : x / 2, ++steps);
    return steps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at your problem is to say that each bit in your number requires an operation and each `1` bit requires another operation. So count the number of bits total and add the number of `1` bits, then subtract one to normalize the result to what is wanted. Another way to say this is to add 1 for a `0` bit and add 2 for a `1` bit. There are multiple ways to do that counting or adding. One way is with a loop over the bits.

Here is a pythonic way to do this.

```
cntsteps = sum(2 if c == '1' else 1 for c in bin(x)[2:]) - 1
```

The `bin` function converts the value to it binary string with a prefix `0x`, the `[2:]` removes that prefix, the `sum(` adds the counts for the bits, and the final `-1` normalizes the result.

If you prefer a method that is more applicable to other languages,

```
def cnt(x):
    if x <= 0:  # handle special case of zero or negative
        return 0
    cntsteps = 0
    while x > 0:
        if x & 1:  # x has a 1 for the least significant bit
            cntsteps += 2
        else:
            cntsteps += 1
        x >>= 1
    return cntsteps - 1
```

Comment: Hey, can you show me the loop method too? How do I go about it?